# Vertical-align not working on table cell containing button

Tags: html, css

The following code is self-explanatory but does not produce the desired effect:

```css
    .t5{margin: auto; width: 50%; font-size: 35px;}
    .t5 td{border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; text-align: center; height:100px;}
    .t5 td.r1{vertical-align: top;};
    .t5 td.r2{vertical-align: middle;}
    .t5 td.r3{vertical-align: bottom;}
```

```html
    <table class="t5">
 
    <tr>
    <td class="r1"><INPUT type = "button"   value = " Does not align at top"></td>
    <td class="r2"><INPUT type = "button"   value = " Does not align in middle"></td>
    <td class="r3">Large Text</td> 
    </tr> 
 
    </table>
```

I have tried using `line-height` to rectify the problem, but cannot get it to resolve the issue completely.

If `font-size: 35px;` is removed, `vertical-align` works properly.

Comment: which browser you're using?! in  chrome 40 your code seems to work perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/haxuq3a8/

Comment: Seconded: works fine in Chrome.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't work in Chrome, for me.... (win 7)

Comment: Working great here in Firefox 36

Comment: The problem is not with the chrome. have you checked the jsfiddle ?! maybe there is another code in your script which resets the middle vertical align?

Comment: There is an extra `;` at the end of `.t5 td.r1{vertical-align: top;};` that should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, when you increase `font-size`, browsers will also increase [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height)'s initial value:

> **normal**: Tells user agents to set the used value to a "reasonable" value based on the font of the element. The value has the same meaning
>   as . We recommend a used value for 'normal' between 1.0
>   to 1.2.

That means that, with `font-size: 35px`, a `line-height: normal` will probably be between 35px and 42px.

Therefore, the [line box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting) which contains the button will be, at least, as tall as that value:

> 'line-height' specifies the *minimal* height of line boxes within the
>   element.

However, you button is not so tall. Therefore, the button is vertically aligned inside the line box according to button's [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align):

> [vertical-align] affects the vertical positioning inside a line box of
>   the boxes generated by an inline-level element.

To fix that, you can

- Apply the same `vertical-align` as the table cell to the button.

  You can do this easily with

  ```css
  .t5 input[type=button] {
    vertical-align: inherit;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  .t5 {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  .t5 td {
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .t5 td.r1 {
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .t5 td.r2 {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .t5 td.r3 {
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }
  .t5 input[type=button] {
    vertical-align: inherit;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <table class="t5">
    <tr>
      <td class="r1">
        <input type="button" value="Does not align at top" />
      </td>
      <td class="r2">
        <input type="button" value="Does not align in middle" />
      </td>
      <td class="r3">Large Text</td>  
    </tr>   
  </table>
  ```
- Reduce the `line-height`, so that th height of the line box will be as tall as the button.

  ```css
  .r1, .r2 {
    line-height: 0;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  .t5 {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  .t5 td {
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .t5 td.r1 {
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .t5 td.r2 {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .t5 td.r3 {
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }
  .r1, .r2 {
    line-height: 0;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <table class="t5">
    <tr>
      <td class="r1">
        <input type="button" value="Does not align at top" />
      </td>
      <td class="r2">
        <input type="button" value="Does not align in middle" />
      </td>
      <td class="r3">Large Text</td>  
    </tr>   
  </table>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the line-height of your first 2 `td`s to 0 by adding `td.r1, td.r2{line-height: 0;}` to your CSS and it will work.

```css
.t5{margin: auto; width: 50%; font-size: 35px;}
.t5 td{border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; text-align: center; height:100px;}
.t5 td.r1{vertical-align: top;}
.t5 td.r2{vertical-align: middle;}
.t5 td.r3{vertical-align: bottom;}
td.r1, td.r2{line-height: 0;}
```

```html
<table class="t5">

<tr>
<td class="r1" valign="top"><INPUT type = "button"   value = " Does not align at top"></td>
<td class="r2" valign="middle"><INPUT type = "button"   value = " Does not align in middle"></td>
<td class="r3">Large Text</td>  
</tr>   

</table>
```

Comment: Good :-) , if your problem is solved then you should accept the answer ;)